# Why does Box<trait> have a different size than Box<struct>?

Tags: polymorphism, rust

Consider the code:

```
use std::boxed::Box;
use std::mem::transmute;

trait Total {
    fn total(&self) -> i32;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct S {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
    c: i32,
}

impl S {
    fn new() -> S {
        S { a: 2, b: 3, c: 4 }
    }
}

impl Total for S {
    fn total(&self) -> i32 {
        self.a + self.b + self.c
    }
}

fn main() {
    let b: Box<Total> = Box::new(S::new());
    unsafe {
        let s: Box<S> = std::mem::transmute(b);
        println!("S = {:?}", s);
    }
}
```

This gives the error:

```
error[E0512]: transmute called with differently sized types: Box<Total> (128 bits) to Box<S> (64 bits)
  --> src/main.rs:30:29
   |
30 |             let s: Box<S> = std::mem::transmute(b);
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Given that `Box<Total>` *is* really a `Box<S>`, why do we get this error?

Comment: Was `let b: Box<Total>` what you meant?

Comment: I've removed [the second and apparently less important question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unlike most languages featuring OO-concepts which embed virtual pointers in `class`, Rust uses the fat-pointer approach in which it carries both the virtual pointer and `struct` pointer alongside each other.

As a result, the layout of `Box<Trait>` for a `S` is:

```
+-------+-------+
| v-ptr | S-ptr |
+-------+-------+
```

which is 128-bits on a 64-bits platform.

---

As for downcasting, at the moment you can use the [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/any/trait.Any.html) type and its `downcast_ref` and `downcast_mut`.

You may also be interested in the [query_interface](https://docs.rs/query_interface/0.3.3/query_interface/) crate for more elaborate use cases.

Answer (score 6):

A [*trait object*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/trait-objects.html), such as `Box<Trait>` or `&Trait`, [contains two pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/raw/struct.TraitObject.html):

- A pointer to the data
- A pointer to the *vtable*

Two pointers (on 64-bit machines) adds up to 128 bits.

A `Box<Struct>` only contains a single pointer, directly to the data. No vtable is needed because the specific methods are able to be resolved statically at compile time. This single pointer is only 64 bits.

> Given that `Box<Total>` is really a `Box<S>`

They are not. If they *were* the same, why would they have different names? :-)